# How to convert each int to a string so i can calculate the result

Tags: android

I'm trying to make an app that can calculate some engineering equations.

I'm getting this error:
Operator '/' cannot be applied to 'android.widget.EditText', 'int'

This is my java:

```
public void onButtonClick(View v){
    machineOD_input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.machineOD_input);
    pipeOD_input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pipeOD_input);
    pipe_length_input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pipe_length_input);
    drive_length_input = (EditText)     findViewById(R.id.drive_length_input);
    muck_up_input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.muck_up_input);
    jacking_speed_input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.jacking_speed_input);

    lub_result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lub_result);
    volume_per_meter_result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.volume_per_meter_result);
    volume_per_pipe_result = (TextView)  findViewById(R.id.volume_per_pipe_result);
    volume_for_drive_result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.volume_for_drive_result);

    lub_result.setText(lub_result.toString());
    volume_per_meter_result.setText(volume_per_meter_result.toString());
    volume_per_pipe_result.setText(volume_per_pipe_result.toString());
    volume_for_drive_result.setText(volume_for_drive_result.toString());

    volume_per_meter_result = ((3.14159254/4* (machineOD_input/1000)*(machineOD_input/1000))-(3.141592654/4*(pipeOD_input/1000)*(pipeOD_input/1000)))*muck_up_input;


}
```

Yes I'm very new to this, any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: getText() from controls, parse them into double (*not* int), calculate, then return to controls with toString() and setText()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get your editText text and store it in variable.Then do calculation on it.
Check the below code example:

```
public class Calculation extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText machineOD_input, pipeOD_input, pipe_length_input, drive_length_input,muck_up_input,jacking_speed_input;
private TextView lub_result, volume_per_meter_result, volume_per_pipe_result, volume_for_drive_result;
Button button;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.math_code);
    machineOD_input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.machineOD_input);
    pipeOD_input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pipeOD_input);
    pipe_length_input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pipe_length_input);
    drive_length_input = (EditText)     findViewById(R.id.drive_length_input);
    muck_up_input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.muck_up_input);
    jacking_speed_input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.jacking_speed_input);
button=findViewById(R.id.button);
        lub_result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lub_result);
        volume_per_meter_result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.volume_per_meter_result);
        volume_per_pipe_result = (TextView)  findViewById(R.id.volume_per_pipe_result);
        volume_for_drive_result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.volume_for_drive_result);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onButtonClick(v);
    }
});

}
public void onButtonClick(View v){


double machine_od=Double.parseDouble(machineOD_input.getText().toString())/1000.0;
double pipe_OD=Double.parseDouble(pipeOD_input.getText().toString())/1000.0;
double muck_up=Double.parseDouble(muck_up_input.getText().toString())/1000.0;
      double  volume_per_meter_res = ((3.14159254/4* (machine_od)*(machine_od))-
                (3.141592654/4*(pipe_OD)*(pipe_OD)))*muck_up;
        volume_per_meter_result.setText(String.valueOf(volume_per_meter_res));

    }

}
```

Comment: how and where can I initialize the variable? I'm getting errors "Variable xxxx might not have been initialised".
 I did this for each variable but they are not initialised :

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private EditText machineOD_input;
    }

Comment: Upload your code.

Comment: Initialise all your view in your oncreate method and all your variable in your onbuttonclick method.

Comment: I can't upload, too long error.
Can you give example please>

Comment: Check the updated answer.